# XQuery Transformation

Tags: mule

We are an EE Customer and currently on 3.5.2. I am migrating an app from 3.5.2 to 3.6. I am noticing that what was working in in 3.5.2 is no longer working in 3.6 Below is the code fragment

```
<logger message="PANPW2 #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" doc:name="Property"/>
<mulexml:xquery-transformer name="xqueryAvatier">
    <mulexml:xquery-text>
        <![CDATA[
            xquery version "3.0";
            declare namespace soapenv = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
            declare namespace ivr = "http://example.com/IVR";  
            declare variable $document external;
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ivr="http://example.com/IVR">
               <soapenv:Header/>
               <soapenv:Body>
                    {$document}
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
                    ]]>
    </mulexml:xquery-text>
</mulexml:xquery-transformer>
<logger message="PANPWFlow3 #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>                        
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
<logger message="PANPWFlow4 #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

The last dom to xml transformer is not producing an xml document and is returning a DOM object net.sf.saxon.dom.ElementOverNodeInfo@104000 
The PANPW2 logger outputs xml document. The logger PANPWFlow3 is outputting a DOM object which is right. The dom-xml transformer succeeding is doing nothing. This was working with 3.5.2 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of the `xquery-transformer` has changed between 3.5.2 and 3.6.

- [3.5.2](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.2/modules/xml/src/main/java/org/mule/module/xml/transformer/XQueryTransformer.java#L84): `setReturnDataType(DataTypeFactory.create(Element.class));`
- [3.6.2](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.6.2/modules/xml/src/main/java/org/mule/module/xml/transformer/XQueryTransformer.java#L87): `setReturnDataType(DataTypeFactory.create(List.class));`

`dom-to-xml-transformer` does not support `List` as a source type, so it is just skipped.

To fix the issue, you need to decide what you want to do with the returned list:

- Use a `for-each` or an `all` to deal with all the `List` elements (as shown [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XQuery+Transformer#XQueryTransformer-Example)). Inside the `for-each` or `all`, the `dom-to-xml-transformer` will then work because the message payload would then be an DOM Element,
- Assume the list is a singleton and set its first entry as the payload before `dom-to-xml-transformer` with:

  ```
  <set-payload value="#[message.payload[0]]" />
  ```

Comment: Thanks David I will work on it and get back to you. Once again thanks for the timely suggestion.

Comment: Once again Thanks David I used the singleton option as that was applicable to me.